# One to One/Zero relationship issue Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have for complicated historical reasons two tables:

Employee

```
   [Key]
   public int employee_ID { get; set; }
   public Nullable<int> employeeStatus_ID { get; set; }
   public string employeeFirstName { get; set; }
   public string employeeSurname { get; set; }
   ...
```

User

```
   [Key]
   public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }
   ...
   public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
```

A User must have an employee record.  An employee record may not (yet) have a user record.

In my data context I have this set as so

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(p => p.Employee)
                .WithOptional(x=>x.User);
```

Behind the scenes Entity Framework created an integer Foreign key Employee_employee_ID on the users object.   I can't reference it but it's there.

And all I thought was good.  However in certain circumstances an employee is effectively upgraded to a user and so I have a function something like this:

```
   employee = GetMyEmployee(employeeID);

      User NewUser = new User
                {
                    UserId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Username = userName,
                    ...
                    Employee = employee
                };

                Context.Users.Add(NewUser);
                Context.SaveChanges();
```

It saves OK, and a new user is created.
Unfortunately I've discovered a new duplicate copy of my employee is also created with a new employee_id.

How can I stop this?
Using Entity Framework 6.01

Comment: Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: I followed the article and used the attach method
           Context.Employees.Attach(employee);

This resolved the issue.  Thanks Colin

Comment: @Colin you should better post it as answer so that it becomes easier to find